# only retain alphanumeric values using regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a text, where I need to remove the product IDs where the expected result must be as show below. How do I remove it using the js replace function

I ahve tried with

```
x.replace(/[a-z)-9]/g,"")

     var x = "Top Knobs, Regent's Park, Knobs and Pulls, TK3112AG, TK3112BSN, 
M1197, M1198, M1199, M1288, M1289, M1648, M1649, M1745, M1746, M1747, 
    M1748, M1749, M1750, M1751, M1752, M1753, M1754, M1755, M2700, M2701, 
    M2702, M2703, M2704, M2705, M2706, M2707, M2708, M2709, M2710, M2711, 
    M2712, M2713, M2714, M2715, M2716, M2717, M2718, M2719, M2720, M2721, 
    M2722, M2723, M2724, M2725, M2726, M2727, M2728, M2729, M2730, M2731, TK3112BLK, 
        TK3112HB, TK3112PN, TK3112PC, TK3115HB, TK3114PC, TK3116BLK, TK3115PN, 
        TK3117BLK, TK3114AG, TK3116PN, TK3118AG, TK3119BSN, TK3113BSN, TK3116PC, 
        TK3119BLK, TK3113PC, TK3115PC, TK3117PC, TK3117HB, TK3119AG, TK3119HB, 
        TK3117PN, TK3115AG, TK3119PC, TK3118BSN, TK3114PN, TK3118PC, TK3118PN, 
        TK3114HB, TK3115BLK, TK3118HB, TK3114BLK, TK3114BSN, TK3115BSN, TK3113AG, 
        TK3116BSN, TK3113BLK, TK3119PN, TK3116HB, TK3118BLK, TK3117BSN, TK3113PN, 
        TK3113HB, TK3116AG, TK3117AG, TK3112, TK3115, TK3114, TK3116, TK3117, 
        TK3118, TK3119, TK3113, Ash Gray, Brushed Satin Nickel, Flat Black, Honey 
        Bronze, Polished Nickel, Polished Chrome, Open End"
```

**Exected result**

```
Top Knobs, Regent's Park, Knobs and Pulls, Ash Gray, Brushed Satin Nickel, Flat Black, Honey 
Bronze, Polished Nickel, Polished Chrome, Open End
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on your sample data, you want to replace any word with a digit in it with an empty string, including the surrounding space and comma. You can do that with this regex:

```
(^|\s+)\S*\d\S*
```

which looks for beginning of string or one or more spaces, then some number of non-space characters, a digit and some number of non-space characters again (this will match the trailing comma if there is one).

```js
var x = "Top Knobs, Regent's Park, Knobs and Pulls, TK3112AG, TK3112BSN, M1197, M1198, M1199, M1288, M1289, M1648, M1649, M1745, M1746, M1747, M1748, M1749, M1750, M1751, M1752, M1753, M1754, M1755, M2700, M2701, M2702, M2703, M2704, M2705, M2706, M2707, M2708, M2709, M2710, M2711, M2712, M2713, M2714, M2715, M2716, M2717, M2718, M2719, M2720, M2721, M2722, M2723, M2724, M2725, M2726, M2727, M2728, M2729, M2730, M2731, TK3112BLK, TK3112HB, TK3112PN, TK3112PC, TK3115HB, TK3114PC, TK3116BLK, TK3115PN, TK3117BLK, TK3114AG, TK3116PN, TK3118AG, TK3119BSN, TK3113BSN, TK3116PC, TK3119BLK, TK3113PC, TK3115PC, TK3117PC, TK3117HB, TK3119AG, TK3119HB, TK3117PN, TK3115AG, TK3119PC, TK3118BSN, TK3114PN, TK3118PC, TK3118PN, TK3114HB, TK3115BLK, TK3118HB, TK3114BLK, TK3114BSN, TK3115BSN, TK3113AG, TK3116BSN, TK3113BLK, TK3119PN, TK3116HB, TK3118BLK, TK3117BSN, TK3113PN, TK3113HB, TK3116AG, TK3117AG, TK3112, TK3115, TK3114, TK3116, TK3117, TK3118, TK3119, TK3113, Ash Gray, Brushed Satin Nickel, Flat Black, Honey Bronze, Polished Nickel, Polished Chrome, Open End";
        
console.log(x.replace(/(^|\s+)\S*\d\S*/g, ''))
```

Answer (score 2):

We can try simply stripping off the code terms using the following regex:

```regex
\s*[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]*,?\s*
```

Explanation:

```regex
\s*     remove any preceding whitespace
[A-Z]+  one or more uppercase characters
[0-9]+  one or more digits
[A-Z]*  optional uppercase
,?      optional comma
\s*     whitespace
```

```js
var x = "Top Knobs, Regent's Park, Knobs and Pulls, TK3112AG, TK3112BSN, M1197, M1198, M1199, M1288, M1289, M1648, M1649, M1745, M1746, M1747, M1748, M1749, M1750, M1751, M1752, M1753, M1754, M1755, M2700, M2701, M2702, M2703, M2704, M2705, M2706, M2707, M2708, M2709, M2710, M2711, M2712, M2713, M2714, M2715, M2716, M2717, M2718, M2719, M2720, M2721, M2722, M2723, M2724, M2725, M2726, M2727, M2728, M2729, M2730, M2731, TK3112BLK, TK3112HB, TK3112PN, TK3112PC, TK3115HB, TK3114PC, TK3116BLK, TK3115PN, TK3117BLK, TK3114AG, TK3116PN, TK3118AG, TK3119BSN, TK3113BSN, TK3116PC, TK3119BLK, TK3113PC, TK3115PC, TK3117PC, TK3117HB, TK3119AG, TK3119HB, TK3117PN, TK3115AG, TK3119PC, TK3118BSN, TK3114PN, TK3118PC, TK3118PN, TK3114HB, TK3115BLK, TK3118HB, TK3114BLK, TK3114BSN, TK3115BSN, TK3113AG, TK3116BSN, TK3113BLK, TK3119PN, TK3116HB, TK3118BLK, TK3117BSN, TK3113PN, TK3113HB, TK3116AG, TK3117AG, TK3112, TK3115, TK3114, TK3116, TK3117, TK3118, TK3119, TK3113, Ash Gray, Brushed Satin Nickel, Flat Black, Honey Bronze, Polished Nickel, Polished Chrome, Open End";
x = x.replace(/\s*[A-Z]+[0-9]+[A-Z]*,?\s*/g, "");
console.log(x);
```

Answer (score 2):

You might also get all the repeating product ID's:

```
\b[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*(?:,\s*[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*)*,?\s*
```

The pattern matches:

- `\b[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*` A word boundary, match 1+ uppercase chars, 1+ digits and optional uppercase chars
- `(?:` Non capture group

  - `,\s*` Match `,` and optional whitespace chars
  - `[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*` Match 1+ uppercase chars, 1+ digits and optional uppercase chars
- `)*` Close the group and optionally repeat
- `,?\s*` Match an optional `,` and whitespace chars

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/6I43ob/1)

```js
const regex = /\b[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*(?:,\s*[A-Z]+\d+[A-Z]*)*,?\s*/g;
const x = `Top Knobs, Regent's Park, Knobs and Pulls, TK3112AG, TK3112BSN, 
M1197, M1198, M1199, M1288, M1289, M1648, M1649, M1745, M1746, M1747,
    M1748, M1749, M1750, M1751, M1752, M1753, M1754, M1755, M2700, M2701,
    M2702, M2703, M2704, M2705, M2706, M2707, M2708, M2709, M2710, M2711,
    M2712, M2713, M2714, M2715, M2716, M2717, M2718, M2719, M2720, M2721,
    M2722, M2723, M2724, M2725, M2726, M2727, M2728, M2729, M2730, M2731, TK3112BLK,
    TK3112HB, TK3112PN, TK3112PC, TK3115HB, TK3114PC, TK3116BLK, TK3115PN,
    TK3117BLK, TK3114AG, TK3116PN, TK3118AG, TK3119BSN, TK3113BSN, TK3116PC,
    TK3119BLK, TK3113PC, TK3115PC, TK3117PC, TK3117HB, TK3119AG, TK3119HB,
    TK3117PN, TK3115AG, TK3119PC, TK3118BSN, TK3114PN, TK3118PC, TK3118PN,
    TK3114HB, TK3115BLK, TK3118HB, TK3114BLK, TK3114BSN, TK3115BSN, TK3113AG,
    TK3116BSN, TK3113BLK, TK3119PN, TK3116HB, TK3118BLK, TK3117BSN, TK3113PN,
    TK3113HB, TK3116AG, TK3117AG, TK3112, TK3115, TK3114, TK3116, TK3117,
TK3118, TK3119, TK3113, Ash Gray, Brushed Satin Nickel, Flat Black, Honey
Bronze, Polished Nickel, Polished Chrome, Open End`;

console.log(x.replace(regex));
```